# Illegal State Exception while using Handler from Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, handler, android-fragmentactivity

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivity (Unknown Source)
  at placecom.learnenglish.appintro.b$1.run (Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:186)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6509)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:914)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:804)
```

Okay, so this problem has now consumed more than 24 hours of my time. I know it's a small issue and I'm doing something wrong. Firebase crashlytics also says below, what could be wrong ? Can any one help ?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Fragment b{c91d8cf} not attached to Activity
```

Here's my code screencap : 
[image]

Comment: where did you put that code? inside onCreate of the fragment?

Comment: inside onStart()

Comment: Try moving the code to onAttach

Comment: Maybe cancel your callback in onDestroy?

Answer (score 0):

> When you are doing something in fragment add this method to check attach or not.

```
if (isAdded()) {
// TODO Your Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably cause of this from what understand is that getActivity() returns null. This might be because when the timer finishes the fragment is no longer attached. Try this:

```
Activity activity=getActivity()
if(activity!=null&&isAdded())){
  // ur code here
}
```

This way it will not crash but it also might not be suitable for your purpose.

Comment: Yes, this prevents the crash. However, not exactly what I need.

Comment: Most probably you will need to rethink your workflow because if get activity is null there is not much you can do.